# How can I properly call class functions from mysql query arguments?

Tags: mysql, node.js, oop

I have the following problem when trying to call a class function from inside a mysql query in NodeJS "ReferenceError: addUser is not defined" I'm getting this error from line 17 this.addUser(uniqueID) any help would greatly help thanks!

```
class Database {

    addUser(uniqueID) {
        this.client.fetchUser(uniqueID)
            .then((User) => {
                this.execute(`INSERT INTO trivia (uniqueID, username, points) VALUES ('${uniqueID}', '${User.username}', '0')`);
            })      
    }

    addPoints(uniqueID, points) {

        var q = `SELECT * FROM trivia WHERE uniqueID = '${uniqueID}'`;

        this.con.query(q, uniqueID, function(err, result, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            if(result.length == 0) {
                this.addUser(uniqueID);
            } 
        })
    }
}
```

My goal is to be able to add a new user to the database after checking if the user already exists or not.

Comment: This is a binding problem. Read about [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).